# Prevent browser back button for a specific page only in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I am trying to prevent browser back button for a specific page only in react redux project.  Lets say I have four pages.

`http://localhost:3000/abc/#/page1`,

`http://localhost:3000/abc/#/page2`,

`http://localhost:3000/abc/#/page3`

and `http://localhost:3000/abc/#/page4`

etc

For all the pages user can go back and forth except `page4`. Once user has visited `page3` and clicked the next button he can not go back.

I have tried multiple options but none of them is working as expected. Below code is working as per my expectation but its blocking browser back for all the pages.

```
componentDidMount() {
   window.history.pushState(null, document.title, window.location.href);
   window.addEventListener('popstate', function (event){
       window.history.pushState(null, document.title,  window.location.href);
   });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `react-router` or `react-router-dom` then you can conditionally disable back button for browser based on current route path.

You can use `withRouter` Higher order component from `react-router` or `react-router-dom`, if your component is not a direct route component.

```
componentDidMount() {
   const { match } = this.props;
   if(match.url === "/abc/#/page4"){
     window.history.pushState(null, document.title, window.location.href);
     window.addEventListener('popstate', function (event){
        window.history.pushState(null, document.title,  window.location.href);
     });
   }      
}
```

Comment: I have already tried this. This way you will not be able to register your listner coz componentDidMount will execute once.

Answer (score 2):

**You can do it using react-router-dom**

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

let history = useHistory();
history.replace("/login");
```

**If you want to do it in logout function :**

```
const logoutClicked = () => {
    localStorage.clear(); //if you want to clear localstorage data
    history.replace("/login"); //redirect to login
  };
```

**If react-router-dom is version >6, use useNavigate instead of useHistory:**

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
const navigate = useNavigate();
navigate("/login");
```

Comment: For more recent versions of react-router-dom, you need to use useNavigate instead of useHistory. See here: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-export-usehistory-was-not-found-in-react-router-dom#:~:text=To%20solve%20the%20error%20"export,that%20lets%20you%20navigate%20programmatically.